# Intraclass Correlation in Python Module?

Tags: python, statistics, correlation

I'm looking to calculate [intraclass correlation (ICC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intraclass_correlation) in Python. I haven't been able to find an existing module that has this feature. Is there an alternate name, or should I do it myself? I'm aware this question was asked [a year ago](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/177091/inter-intra-class-correlation-coefficient-or-intra-inter-concordance-coeff) on Cross Validated by another user, but there were no replies. I am looking to compare the continuous scores between two raters.

Comment: You might want to also see [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/63368/61867) question, which includes some code. I'm familiar with quite a few functions in numpy, but I haven't seen ICC before. You might also want to search the docs of the scikit-learn and statsmodels packages. It doesn't seem too hard to implement by hand either way. Do consider using numpy, especially if speed is important to you. Don't forget to post your answer here, to help others searching for this in future!

Comment: Thanks Praveen. That's what WalR provided as well. At this point, it would have been faster to write it myself. When searching for an implementation in python, most results coming up for ICC were Intel C++ Compiler. I hadn't found it buried in neurolearn. Someone may find it useful to implement ICC completely in scipy/numpy. I'll followup with the implementation or code I use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find an implementation at [ICC](https://github.com/nipy/nipype/blob/master/nipype/algorithms/icc.py) or [Brain_Data.icc](https://github.com/cosanlab/nltools/blob/master/nltools/data/brain_data.py)

Comment: I didn't find that before. That is an implementation of ICC(3,1) specifically. I'd like to see if an implementation of all ICC variants exist in a module. I believe I need ICC(2,2), which I can code, if no implementation exists.

Comment: @Hector There is an other implementation for `icc2` check my edit  and good luck.

Comment: @Hector So glad to help.

Answer (score 10):

There are several implementations of the [ICC](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ICC/versions/2.3.0) in [R](https://www.r-project.org/). These can be used from Python via the [rpy2](https://rpy2.bitbucket.io/) package. Example:

```python
from rpy2.robjects import DataFrame, FloatVector, IntVector
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from math import isclose

groups = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4,
          4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8]
values = [1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 8, 1, 4, 6, 4, 3,
          3, 6, 5, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 2, 8, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8]

r_icc = importr("ICC")
df = DataFrame({"groups": IntVector(groups),
                "values": FloatVector(values)})
icc_res = r_icc.ICCbare("groups", "values", data=df)
icc_val = icc_res[0] # icc_val now holds the icc value

# check whether icc value equals reference value
print(isclose(icc_val, 0.728, abs_tol=0.001))
```

Comment: Using R and python together is even easier now with JupyterLab.

Comment: You can also use python and R together by just using RStudio and making a new chunk with ctrl + I and renaming it to python (after loading the reticulate package with library(reticulate)).

Answer (score 8):

The [pengouin](https://pingouin-stats.org/generated/pingouin.intraclass_corr.html) library computes ICC in 6 different ways, along with associated confidence levels and p values.

You can install it with `pip install pingouin` or `conda install -c conda-forge pingouin`

```
import pingouin as pg
data = pg.read_dataset('icc')
icc = pg.intraclass_corr(data=data, targets='Wine', raters='Judge',
                         ratings='Scores')
```

```
data.head()

|    |   Wine | Judge   |   Scores |
|---:|-------:|:--------|---------:|
|  0 |      1 | A       |        1 |
|  1 |      2 | A       |        1 |
|  2 |      3 | A       |        3 |
|  3 |      4 | A       |        6 |
|  4 |      5 | A       |        6 |
|  5 |      6 | A       |        7 |
|  6 |      7 | A       |        8 |
|  7 |      8 | A       |        9 |
|  8 |      1 | B       |        2 |
|  9 |      2 | B       |        3 |
```

icc

```
|    | Type   | Description             |   ICC |      F |   df1 |   df2 |        pval | CI95%        |
|---:|:-------|:------------------------|------:|-------:|------:|------:|------------:|:-------------|
|  0 | ICC1   | Single raters absolute  | 0.773 | 11.199 |     5 |    12 | 0.000346492 | [0.39, 0.96] |
|  1 | ICC2   | Single random raters    | 0.783 | 27.966 |     5 |    10 | 1.42573e-05 | [0.25, 0.96] |
|  2 | ICC3   | Single fixed raters     | 0.9   | 27.966 |     5 |    10 | 1.42573e-05 | [0.65, 0.98] |
|  3 | ICC1k  | Average raters absolute | 0.911 | 11.199 |     5 |    12 | 0.000346492 | [0.65, 0.99] |
|  4 | ICC2k  | Average random raters   | 0.915 | 27.966 |     5 |    10 | 1.42573e-05 | [0.5, 0.99]  |
|  5 | ICC3k  | Average fixed raters    | 0.964 | 27.966 |     5 |    10 | 1.42573e-05 | [0.85, 0.99] |
```

Answer (score 1):

The [R](https://www.r-project.org/) package [psych](http://personality-project.org/r/html/ICC.html) has an implementation of the Intraclass Correlations (ICC) that calculates many types of variants including ICC(1,1), ICC(1,k), ICC(2,1), ICC(2,k), ICC(3,1) and ICC(3,k) plus other metrics.

[This page](https://www.uvm.edu/~dhowell/methods9/Supplements/icc/More%20on%20ICCs.pdf) has a good comparison between the different variants,

You can use the R ICC function via [rpy2](https://rpy2.bitbucket.io/) package.

Example:

1. First install `psych` and `lme4` in R:

```
install.packages("psych")
install.packages("lme4")
```

2. Calculate ICC coefficients in Python using rpy2:

```
import rpy2
from rpy2.robjects import IntVector, pandas2ri
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

psych = importr("psych")

values = rpy2.robjects.r.matrix(
    IntVector(
        [9,    2,   5,    8,
        6,    1,   3,    2,
        8,    4,   6,    8,
        7,    1,   2,    6,
        10,   5,   6,    9,
        6,   2,   4,    7]),
    ncol=4, byrow=True
)

icc = psych.ICC(values)

# Convert to Pandas DataFrame
icc_df = pandas2ri.rpy2py(icc[0])
```

Results:

```
                            type    ICC        F           df1   df2    p          lower bound   upper bound  
  Single_raters_absolute    ICC1    0.165783   1.794916    5.0   18.0   0.164720   -0.132910     0.722589     
  Single_random_raters      ICC2    0.289790   11.026650   5.0   15.0   0.000135   0.018791      0.761107     
  Single_fixed_raters       ICC3    0.714829   11.026650   5.0   15.0   0.000135   0.342447      0.945855     
  Average_raters_absolute   ICC1k   0.442871   1.794916    5.0   18.0   0.164720   -0.884193     0.912427     
  Average_random_raters     ICC2k   0.620080   11.026650   5.0   15.0   0.000135   0.071153      0.927240     
  Average_fixed_raters      ICC3k   0.909311   11.026650   5.0   15.0   0.000135   0.675657      0.985891
```

Comment: So in this case each column is a "group" or "cluster"?

Comment: Ah, I see nevermind. In this example, there seems to be 4 judges and 6 subjects. https://www.uvm.edu/~statdhtx/StatPages/icc/icc-overall.html.

So generally speaking, the rows are the "clusters" and the columns are the number of observations you have within each cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Brain_Data](https://github.com/cosanlab/nltools/blob/master/nltools/data/brain_data.py), I modified the code in order to calculate the correlation coefficients ICC(2,1), ICC(2,k), ICC(3,1) or ICC(3,k) for data input as a table Y (subjects in rows and repeated measurements in columns).

```
import os
import numpy as np
from numpy import ones, kron, mean, eye, hstack, dot, tile
from numpy.linalg import pinv

def icc(Y, icc_type='ICC(2,1)'):
    ''' Calculate intraclass correlation coefficient

    ICC Formulas are based on:
    Shrout, P. E., & Fleiss, J. L. (1979). Intraclass correlations: uses in
    assessing rater reliability. Psychological bulletin, 86(2), 420.
    icc1:  x_ij = mu + beta_j + w_ij
    icc2/3:  x_ij = mu + alpha_i + beta_j + (ab)_ij + epsilon_ij
    Code modifed from nipype algorithms.icc
    https://github.com/nipy/nipype/blob/master/nipype/algorithms/icc.py

    Args:
        Y: The data Y are entered as a 'table' ie. subjects are in rows and repeated
            measures in columns
        icc_type: type of ICC to calculate. (ICC(2,1), ICC(2,k), ICC(3,1), ICC(3,k)) 
    Returns:
        ICC: (np.array) intraclass correlation coefficient
    '''

    [n, k] = Y.shape

    # Degrees of Freedom
    dfc = k - 1
    dfe = (n - 1) * (k-1)
    dfr = n - 1

    # Sum Square Total
    mean_Y = np.mean(Y)
    SST = ((Y - mean_Y) ** 2).sum()

    # create the design matrix for the different levels
    x = np.kron(np.eye(k), np.ones((n, 1)))  # sessions
    x0 = np.tile(np.eye(n), (k, 1))  # subjects
    X = np.hstack([x, x0])

    # Sum Square Error
    predicted_Y = np.dot(np.dot(np.dot(X, np.linalg.pinv(np.dot(X.T, X))),
                                X.T), Y.flatten('F'))
    residuals = Y.flatten('F') - predicted_Y
    SSE = (residuals ** 2).sum()

    MSE = SSE / dfe

    # Sum square column effect - between colums
    SSC = ((np.mean(Y, 0) - mean_Y) ** 2).sum() * n
    MSC = SSC / dfc  # / n (without n in SPSS results)

    # Sum Square subject effect - between rows/subjects
    SSR = SST - SSC - SSE
    MSR = SSR / dfr

    if icc_type == 'icc1':
        # ICC(2,1) = (mean square subject - mean square error) /
        # (mean square subject + (k-1)*mean square error +
        # k*(mean square columns - mean square error)/n)
        # ICC = (MSR - MSRW) / (MSR + (k-1) * MSRW)
        NotImplementedError("This method isn't implemented yet.")

    elif icc_type == 'ICC(2,1)' or icc_type == 'ICC(2,k)':
        # ICC(2,1) = (mean square subject - mean square error) /
        # (mean square subject + (k-1)*mean square error +
        # k*(mean square columns - mean square error)/n)
        if icc_type == 'ICC(2,k)':
            k = 1
        ICC = (MSR - MSE) / (MSR + (k-1) * MSE + k * (MSC - MSE) / n)

    elif icc_type == 'ICC(3,1)' or icc_type == 'ICC(3,k)':
        # ICC(3,1) = (mean square subject - mean square error) /
        # (mean square subject + (k-1)*mean square error)
        if icc_type == 'ICC(3,k)':
            k = 1
        ICC = (MSR - MSE) / (MSR + (k-1) * MSE)

    return ICC
```

Comment: I have an question on the input data. I have a number of observers and they all measure a number of stimuli three times. So, rows are subjects and columns are the three repeated measurements for a single stimuli. Does that mean I can only calculate ICC for one stimuli?

Comment: Exactly. For each stimuli and each observer you can calculate the intraobserver variability with the ICC. Hence the columns are the three repeated measurements and the rows the subjects.