# Interclass Correlation Coefficient (ICC(3,k)) with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, spss

I am trying to compute an ICC(3,k) for k=2 or more for columns in a pandas dataframe. 
I could not find any toolboxes for this, only [this post from 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40965579/intraclass-correlation-in-python-module/48277559) (the Brain toolbox does not exist anymore). There is a code sample for ICC(3,1) but numpy and not pandas based. I am a little lost on how to re-work this.

Basically, I want to mimic the IBM SPSS toolbox for dataframes I already have created.

I have a number of measurements performed by 2 (or more) independent observers on a number of subjects.

I have a dataframe of the form (columns are multiindex):

```
          meas1        meas2         meas3
         obs1 obs2    obs1 obs2     obs1 obs2 
subject1 
subject2
subject3
...
```

I would like to compute the ICC for every measurement.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [pingouin stats package for ICC calculation.](https://pingouin-stats.org/generated/pingouin.intraclass_corr.html) Since it is a python library, it doesn't need you to install R or SPSS.

You just need to drop the index to a single column as measurement. You can refer to their ICC wine dataset for information about how to rearrange your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rpy2 module. It has the same functions as in R. Probably, you can check if both R and SPSS implementations are similar.